# Conditional Probability Problem

Tags: probability

> An insurance company examines its pool of auto insurance customers and gathers the following information:
>
> (i)  All customers insure at least 1 car
>
> (ii)  64% of all customers insure more than one car
>
> (iii)  20% of the customers insure a sports car
>
> (iv)  Of those customers who insure more than one car, 15% insure a sports car.
>
> What is the probability that a randomly selected customer insures exactly one car, and that car is not a sports car?

Let's use the following variable definitions:

O= owns 1 car, O' = owns more than 1 car

S= sports car, S' = Not sports car.

N() = Cardinal Number of a set

---

From statements (i)-(iii), we get the following:  $N(O') = 64, N(O) = 36, N(S) = 20$

From statement (iv):  $\Pr(S \mid O')=15$

We are asked to find $\Pr(S' \mid O)$

---

By definition:
$Pr(S' \mid O) = \cfrac{\Pr(S' \cap O)}{\Pr(O)}=\cfrac{\Pr(S' \cap O)}{N(O)}\tag{1}$

Pr()=N() since this is a uniform distribution--I interpret this when it says "randomly selected"

Next, I did:

$N(S)=N(S \cap O') + N(S \cap O)\tag{2}$

$0.2 = .64*.15 + .36 * x$

$x=0.28$, but we want 1-x because we want S' in $\Pr(S' \cap O)$ which equals 0.72.

See diagram below:

[image: Tree diagram]

So plugging back into (1):

$Pr(S' \mid O) = \cfrac{0.71*.36}{.36}=.71$

but the answer is .26.

**I mainly wanted to know why equation (2) is wrong.  I know that is the crux of the problem.  Why can't I use that equation in this case?**

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: By the way is there any way to do flow charts or tree diagrams easily here so I don't have to keep taking pictures?

Comment: Equation $2$ is correct.

Comment: Will not be able to write an answer for quite a while (cooking dinner). The probability of $S'\cap O$ is certainly not $0.72$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Never mind.  it looks like I solved it right but I was solving for the wrong thing!  The question is asking for $Pr(O \cap S')$ when I was solving for $Pr(S' \mid O)$.  I always get the  language confused.  If you use my calculations I get the right answer.  Thanks.  Have a good dinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is very simple. The question asks for the probability $\mathrm P(S'\cap O)$ not $\mathrm P(S'|O)$.

Two things: I don't like the notation where probabilities are greater than 1. Divide them by a hundred or at least put percentage symbols. Also, your notation is rather convoluted. There's no need to define a counting function and a probability function when, as you know, both are identical here.

Comment: I second: "don't like notation where probabilities are greater than  1".

Comment: Thanks @Sharkos.  So it looks like I did it all correctly I just solved for the wrong thing.  It seems like a lot of people get the language confused when they are asking for intersections and conditional probabilities.  Do you have any tips?

Comment: "What is the probability that [X] and [Y] happen?" is pretty unambiguous; it's got nothing like "given that" to indicate a conditional. Just try writing X,Y,Z for bits of the question and removing unnecessary grammar to pick out the mathematical content of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem number 10 from the SOA/CAS Exam P practice problems, which you can download  [here](http://www.beanactuary.org/exams/preliminary/exams/syllabi/ExamPSamplequestions.pdf)

For the solution look [here](http://www.math.osu.edu/%7Eban.1/as/ExamP/P-09-05sol.pdf)

> Consider the following events about a randomly selected auto insurance customer:
> A = Customer insures more than one car
> B = customer insures a sport car
>
> We want to find the probability of the complement of A intersecting the complement of B (exactly one car, non-sports). But $P\left(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}\right) = 1 - P\left(A \cup B\right)$
>
> And, by the Additive Law, $P\left(A \cup B\right) = P\left(A\right) + P\left(B\right) - P\left(A \cap B\right)$
>
> By the Multiplicative law $P\left(A \cap B\right) = P\left(B|A\right)P\left(A\right) = 0.15 \times 0.64 = 0.096$
>
> It follows that $P\left(A\cup B\right) = 0.64 + 0.20 - 0.096 = 0.744$ and $P\left(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}\right) = 1 - 0.744 = 0.256$

Comment: Thanks @yiyi.  I know I have all the solutions, I was trying to understand why what I did was wrong.  The question is asking for $Pr(O \cap S')$ when I was solving for $Pr(S' \mid O)$!  But my calculations are correct.

Comment: I figured that, the hardest part of these problems is correctly understanding the language.

Answer (score 0):

Always start by labeling the events. Let C (stands for Corvette) be the event of insuring a
sports car (not S, because we reserve this for the entire probability space), and M be the
event of insuring multiple cars. Note that M C is the event of insuring exactly one car, as
all customers insure at least one car. We are given that Pr(M ) = 0.70, Pr(C) = 0.20,
 and Pr(C M ) = 0.15. We need to find Pr M C ! CC ( ).
 You need to recall De Morgan’s Laws
and then we see that:
Pr M C ! CC ( ) = Pr (M " C)
C
( ) = 1# Pr(M " C) = 1# Pr(M ) # Pr(C) + Pr(M ! C) =
= 1# Pr(M ) # Pr(C) + Pr(C M )Pr(M ) = 1# 0.70 # 0.20 + 0.15 $ 0.70 = 0.205.